# PgAdmin4 starts empty

Tags: linux, database, pgadmin-4

[image]I installed PostgreSQL and PgAdmin4 on an Ubuntu 19.04 virtualbox guest (following [this guide](https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-on-ubuntu-19-04/))

Now I have the problem that PgAdmin4 does not show anything (after login).

I have an empty Browser (Server) tree, a fully white (blank) dashboard...
In the PgAdmin4 menu I only have the Object tab but if I click it it opens a tiny empty box (as shown in the screenshot above).

In Firefox it was always like that. A couple of times it worked in Chrome (could add server, create databases...) but then, suddenly, even in Chrome it is empty.

Does anyone have a clue what could be wrong?

Comment: Please right-click the create -> server and connect the local database with the pgAdmin4.

Comment: Please follow the link https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-on-ubuntu-19-04/  and go through the 5th step .

Comment: One more thing that, you check that you have PostgreSQL database in the local or live system.

Comment: @YugmaPatel 5th step is login? The only options I get on right click are the panel (add, remove, detach) options. Using psql on the Ubuntu guest system shows the databases I created when it worked. And I can connect to the databases from my .net core apps (Visual Studio) from my machine.

Comment: how did you install it

Comment: I followed this guide: https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-on-ubuntu-19-04/

Comment: Make sure you have static ip address in your virtual box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe some of the packages are missing during installation. here are commands to install properly.

```
sudo apt-get install wget ca-certificates
```

add the GPG key for the repository.

```
 sudo wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

add the repository:

```
 sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'



sudo apt-get update


sudo apt install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
```

During installation process you will be asked to enter an email and set up password. Once finished

navigate to here

localhost/pgadmin4

Comment: I give it a try. Though: the installation actually worked. The few first starts I had a chance to create databases etc. Then, after aprox. 3 times the frontend under pgadmin4 (after the successfull login) shows the empty screen from the screenshot. No dashboard/no chance to create a database (left side is empty...)

Comment: repeating the shown steps plus an additional sudo apt-get updgrade seems to have fixed the problems. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

dear after having the same problem and checking for the solution for about 3 hours,
it  appears to be something  related to the layout reset.

i have solved this issue by :

1- right click on the page

2- select inspect

3- in the console write  `pgAdmin.Settings.show()`

now its reseted