# pgAdmin 4 window is completely blank

Tags: pgadmin-4

No file tab no anything, only shows object tab and that's it.
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lso9i.png), I restarted the pgAdmin server multiple times and reloaded the webpage still same window.

using latest version of pgAdmin4.
using windows 10.

Comment: It seems similar to this problem

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57567252/pgadmin4-starts-empty

Comment: hey thanks for the comment, but nothing is missing I ran it before multiple times and it worked absolutely fine but for some reason it is like this now.

Comment: Damn seems like none has an answer for that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just had the same problem and solved it using this:

1. Right click on the page and select inspect (Google Chrome)
2. Go to console
3. Type in pgAdmin.Settings.show()

Hope this resolves your question!

Comment: yo thanks for the comment so i downloaded a newer version of pgAdmin and its fixed now lel